# Javascript math issue - attribute value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new in javascript code, i have simple question, i'm tryng to attribute new value to my input `<input id="rimonta" type="text" />`,

```
var p = listData.list[0].puntata; //  this return 10 
var x = p + 1  // i want have result 10+1 = 11 
$('#rimonta').val(x); // actually it attribute value 101 and NOT 11
```

I don't know why the math 10 + 1 return 101 and NOT 11. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Because it's `'10' + 1`, not `10 + 1`.

Comment: because its coming back as a string, javascript is dynamically typed, not statically so it seens `p + 1` as `"10" + "1" = "101"` as a string.  You need to cast listdata.list[0].puntata to an int with first

Comment: how can do it "INT" ??

Comment: `parseInt(p) + 1`, or `var p = parseInt(listData.list[0].puntata;`

Comment: you can do it as var p = parsetInt(listData.list[0].puntata,10); 
var x = p + 1  
$('#rimonta').val(x);

Comment: @Geeky thanks for removign your answer, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is most likely due to the fact that p is a string

```
var p = "10";
var x = p + 1;
console.log(x) // returns 101

var p = 10;
var x = p + 1;
console.log(x) // returns 11

var p = "10";
var x = parseInt(p) + 1;
console.log(x) // returns 11
```

Comment: yup! thank you for your help!